# Hashmap And Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, hashmap

I would like to implement something like this:

**What I have**
I have JSON data with `lat` and `lng` values, and I've put all of these into `Hashmap`, I have done it and its working

**What I need**
How I can put these stored `lat` and `lng` values into Google maps, with more Markers?

I have this code for parsing JSON data

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    try {
           for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                String lng = c.getString(TAG_LNG);



            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_LAT, lat);
            map.put(TAG_LNG, lng);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
           }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    }
```

**Problem**

I dont know where I should start, how I can put more than 1 marker into Google Maps?

```
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag=
                    (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            initListNav();
            map=mapFrag.getMap();

            CameraUpdate center=
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latvalue, lngvalue);

            CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13);

            map.moveCamera(center);
            map.animateCamera(zoom);

            addMarker(map, latvalue , lngvalue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it iterating over the array that is the problem than this is how you do that.

```
for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : contactList) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
      .position(new LatLng(hashMap.get(TAG_LAT) , hashMap.get(TAG_LNG)))
      .title("Another marker"));
}
```

EDIT:

```
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    ArrayList<LatLng> contactList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    contactList.add(new LatLng(48.8742, 2.3470));
    contactList.add(new LatLng(0, 0));

    for (LatLng latLon : contactList) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon).title("Another marker"));
    }
```

Edit 2: 
The same with hashmap

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//Paris
{
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(TAG_LAT, "48.8742");
    map.put(TAG_LNG, "2.3470");

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
contactList.add(map);
}

//London
{
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(TAG_LAT, "51.5171");
    map.put(TAG_LNG, "0.1062");

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    contactList.add(map);
}

for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : contactList) {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(hashMap.get(TAG_LAT)) ,        
            Double.parseDouble(hashMap.get(TAG_LNG))))
        .title("Another marker"));
}
```

EDIT 3 , how to get callbacks on marker click:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        Log.e("onMarkerClick", "test: "+arg0.getTitle());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: its still same, There is only 1 marker on map with title Another marker.

Comment: @Tirolel is your `Json` working correctly? Is your `Hashmap` filled with the locations, did you try to print them?

Comment: Are you using the hashmap to something else. If not then test the code i added. Its working code that i just tested

Comment: lambda : I just tried to print values from hashmap, and its all there, i mean the lat and lng values

Comment: Falxie : yea i tried it too, and i got 2 markers, so how i can use my hashmap/array to put the data there instead of the one is been created?

Comment: Added a hashmap version too.

Comment: great thank you very much, ur first solution fixed it for me, I had wrong code in some line, but now they are working fine. But Iam wondering if its possible to click on marker and open it with google maps?

Answer (score -1):

You should be using Google Maps API V2. In the [Google Maps API Demo V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code) you can see how Markers are added to the `GoogleMap mMap`.

```
    // Uses a custom icon.
mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(SYDNEY)
        .title("Sydney")
        .snippet("Population: 4,627,300"));
```

In this example `SYDNEY` is a `LatLong` point and the title and snippet are for the custom infowindow. Just go over your Hashmap and add each marker to the map. You don't necessarily need to assign each Marker to a `Marker` variable (like they did in the example with `mSydney`).

Comment: yea Iam using Google Maps V2. I can get the map, lat and long for 1 single object, but If I want to put more than 1 object into Maps --> Iam lost, I dont know how I can get all objects and insert it into addMarker as a list of lat&long values